# Using id from Facebook as a primary key

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using the id that I get from a graph call to facebook as my primary key for identifying individual users in my database.

```
me?fields=id
```

Which returns something like this :

```
{
  "id": "XXX0393314XXXXXXX"
}
```

Accoring to Facebook :

> The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app
>   and cannot be used across different apps.

Does this make a good match for a primary key, or should I use the user's e-mail address? The reason why I went with the id is because some users use their phone numbers instead of registering with an e-mail. Hence the graph call wouldn't return a valid e-mail. I would need to add a special flow to ask their e-mail and send a confirmation, which is feasible, but more work.

Comment: if you loose app all of your saved data will be of no worth if you save against app scoped id.

Comment: You already kinda answered your own question; it's not guaranteed to get an email using FB login. Since you can't related App-Scoped User IDs, the ID is really only to identify FB users of your app.